# My Controller Won't Work!

Tags: magento2, controllers

I'm trying to create a module which displays a CMS block with a custom route on which I can add some logic etc.

But I can't get the Module's controller to work.

The route I'm trying to create is `www.example.com/wholesalers/info` but when I go to that page url I get a **404 page**.

I've followed [this mageplaza tutorial](https://www.mageplaza.com/magento-2-module-development/how-to-create-controllers-magento-2.html) but I can't get it to work.

I've been looking and looking but can't see what I'm missing...

### Module Structure

```
app/code/Holy/
└── Wholesalers
    ├── composer.json
    ├── registration.php
    ├── Block
    │   └── Info.php
    ├── Controller
    │   └── Info
    │       └── Index.php
    ├── etc
    │   ├── module.xml
    │   └── routes.xml
    └── view
        └── frontend
            ├── layout
            │   └── wholesalers_info_index.xml
            └── templates
                └── wholesale-info.phtml
```

### composer.json

```
{
    "name": "Holy/module-Wholesalers",
    "description": "",
    "minimum-stability": "dev",
    "require": {},
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Holy\\Wholesalers\\": ""
        },
        "files": [
            "registration.php"
        ]
    }
}
```

### registration.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @category   Local
 * @package    Holy_Wholesalers
 */

\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Holy_Wholesalers',
    __DIR__
);
```

### etc/module.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" ?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Holy_Wholesalers" setup_version="1.0.0"/>
</config>
```

### etc/routes.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:App/etc/routes.xsd">
    <router id="standard">
        <route id="wholesalers" frontName="wholesalers">
            <module name="Holy_Wholesalers" />
        </route>
    </router>
</config>
```

### Controller/Info/Index.php

```
<?php
/**
 * @category   Local
 * @package    Holy_Wholesale
 */

namespace Holy\Wholesalers\Controller\Info;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $_pageFactory;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $pageFactory)
    {
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        return parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        return $this->_pageFactory->create();
    }
}
```

### view/frontend/layout/wholesalers_info_index.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" layout="2columns" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <referenceContainer name="content">
        <block class="Holy\Wholesalers\Block\Info" name="customer_wholesale_info" template="Holy_Wholesalers::wholesale-info.phtml" />
    </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

### view/frontend/templates/wholesale-info.phtml

```
<h1>Hello World</h1>
```

### And...

My Magento instance is in developer mode and I've cleared the cache etc

```
php bin/magento cache:flush
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

Comment: my phtml isn't working, is there anything else i need to add

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try moving your `routes.xml` to `etc/frontend/routes.xml`

```
cache:clean + setup:upgrade + setup:di:compile
```

Comment: you faster than me, upvote for you ;)

Answer (score 2):

Try moving **etc/routes.xml** file to **etc/frontend/routes.xml**